# Cant access certain websites in my ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ip, traceroute

I can access all the websites except a few websites- particularly that of my own college!

When I did `nslookup www.iitm.ac.in` I got the IP, but when I ping that particular IP, I get nothing.

What can be the problem here? How can I resolve this issue?
ALso I ran "traceroute www.iitm.ac.in" and got the following:

[image]

Comment: I can access that website. Suggest you edit your question to include a traderoute - "tracert www.iitm.ac.in" under windows, "traceroute www.iitm.ac.in" under Linux

Comment: I ran that command i.e traceroute www.iitm.ac.in but i got gateway in first row and then some ip in second row followed by *** in all subsequent rows

Comment: I think the only answer here is to report the problem to your Internet Service Provider

Comment: Likely nothing to do with Ubuntu per se since I can access it with mine. What does `wget http://iitmwww.iitm.ac.in` says? What does `route` says (when you cannot access it)?

Answer (score 3):

I can't also ping from here :)
But I can access the web site using a browser.

That means that site is ignoring ping requests, which is usually done for security reasons (see the answers from here: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4440/security-risk-of-ping).

For example, [in linux](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/Security/disable_ping.htm) ping can be disabled like this:

`# echo 1 >/proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_all`

Comment: The problem is not just "pinging". The main problem is-- I cant access the website itself! Also everyone here can access the same website but me! I guess the problem lies with my ubuntu.

Comment: You can fake an HTTP request with `curl -s -I https://www.iitm.ac.in/`. Do you get a `200 OK` code in the first line? If so, maybe try with another browser? Another possibility could be a wrong proxy (?)

Comment: No I did not get anything! It returned me the next prompt thats all! Also I tried accessing the website from chrome(I am currently using mozilla) but it showed-
This site cant be reached, www.iitm.ac.in took too long to respond

Comment: In that case I feel it can't help you with that, I am sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to set the correct DNS server, usually a one offered by your university. I have seen this happen before.

If you're using Google DNS, some web-sites of your university may not accessible, but once you set the DNS to the one offered by your university, they will be.